# How to set Alt text in PowerPoint when using Office.Document interface?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I have built an extension that adds images to PowerPoint. It works just fine. Now, I want to add Alt Text to the image when inserting the image.
I don't see any option for that in the documentation.

I did try the following, and it (as expected!) did not work.

```
export const insertImage = async (image) => {
  // insert the image into the document.
  try {
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(
      image,
      {
        coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Image,
        altText: "alt text test",
      },
      (asyncResult) => {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
          throw asyncResult.error.message;
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Currently, setting alt text is not a part of the product. We track Office Add-in feature requests on our Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum ( https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions). Please add your request there. Feature requests are considered when we go through our planning process. 
Thanks, Microsoft 365 Developer Platform team ​